# Preg_replace for Integers

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, integer

For some reason when I use `preg_replace()` for a input field that stores phone numbers, I can't store it into MySQL.  Can preg_replace be used for integers or can it only be used for strings?

I am trying to make it impossible to input letters into the text field.. Can someone give some insight?

```
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
```

//when I use preg_replace, it doesn't store the value in MySQL

```
$tel = preg_replace($reg_num,'', $tel);
```

...

```
    $st->bindParam(6, $tel, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: please try $tel = str_replace($reg_num,'', $tel);

Comment: show your `$reg_num` var

Comment: REGEX patterns are written in, and act on, strings only, even if either part contains numbers. What is the value of `$reg_num`?

Comment: You're replacing the matched with an empty string `''`. Are you sure `$tel` isn't empty after the `preg_replace()`? Have you tried `echo $tel;` before you insert it in the DB?

Comment: @Utkanos  $reg_num is  $reg_num = "/[^[:num:]]/";

Comment: @Havelock Yes, when I echo $tel, it is a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_replace` will cast the Integer as a String, and perform the replace correctly. However, it will return a String where `bindParam` is expecting an Integer.

Storing a phone number as an Integer is usually ill-advised as you would lose any leading '0' or any '+' sign (if used for international numbers).

Comment: `preg_replace` didn't receive an integer argument, so there was no "cast" involved.  Otherwise I agree 100%.

Comment: Good call :) Presumably it would automatically cast if it did receive an Integer?

Comment: Well, bearing in mind PHP is loosely typed it's difficult to say what is meant by an "integer argument".  But even an integer literal would be cast to a string, so I suppose you are right yes.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the problem may be that PDO is expecting an integer for your telephone parameter whereas the `$tel` variable contains a string.  Try instead:

```
$st->bindParam(6, int($tel), PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

However, you should probably store telephone numbers as strings (but this may require a change to your schema):

```
$st->bindParam(6, $tel, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have regular exp.. then simply use str_replace();

```
$tel = str_replace ($reg_num,'', $tel);
```